# Draw a line in Android without setting it as content

Tags: android

Just a newbie here.

Is it possible to draw a line over a layout?

I have an `XML file(activity_main)` and it contains a layout which is `ImageLayout` that I took from github. The layout contains an image and several buttons.

What I want to do is to draw a line between two points on the layout. In order to draw a line, people usually create a `Draw class` and extends `View`. On the `MainActivity`, they would `setContent` the `Draw class`. I have already `setContent` my XML file. How would I draw a line from this point?

**EDIT:**
I heard about the class `Path`, I think it is better than using onDraw because I would be connecting(drawing lines between) several points in my layout.

Enlighten me about it if you could

Comment: Please show some code and XML.

Comment: I think xml code is not really necessary to show. It is a layout(activity_main) and I set it as `setContent(activity_main)`. I'm asking if drawing a line(between two points or several points) over a layout that has been set as content is possible and if it is, how?

Answer (score 1):

Subclass the container `ViewGroup` and override its `dispatchDraw()` method. I am providing example of subclassed `LinearLayout`, however, this would work with any other `ViewGroup`.

```
public class MyLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
    private Paint paint;

    public MyLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initPaint();
    }

    public MyLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initPaint();
    }

    public MyLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initPaint();
    }

    private void initPaint() {
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawLine(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), paint);
    }
}
```

Comment: onDraw will not be called

Comment: what do you mean by subclass? Create new class and extend `ViewGroup`? If so, how do I put it in `MainActivity` where my layout(activity_main) is set as content.

Comment: The parent view in your XML is a `ViewGroup`, (most probably `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` or some other). Subclass this and then change the class name in xml.

Comment: https://www.aaronmbrown.net/blog/2012/12/android-viewondraw-not-getting-invoked/ and https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/oLccWfszuUo and many more on SO

Comment: by the way: instead of custom ViewGroup you can create custom Drawable class (or use ShapeDrawable with custom Shape class) and use it by calling setBackground(Drawable)

Comment: You were absolutely right about the `onDraw()` not getting called. I edited the answer with tested piece of code. Thank you sir!

Comment: no prob, dispatchDraw() is ok, you can also use draw() (but i'm not 100% sure)

Comment: thanks for the answer, im currently integrating it to my project. btw, how can i use the dispatch draw in another class? i instantiated `MyLinearLayout mll= new MyLinearLayout(this)` then `mll.dispatchDraw()`, what should I put inside the parenthesis?

Comment: I have successfully run it. I put it as `setContentView(mll)` but that is not what I want to achieve. I want `activity_main` as my layout so I want to retain `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` and just draw over that layout. How?

Comment: Just put it in your xml of `activity_main`. Instead of first tag being `<LinearLayout>` it will be `<MyLinearLayout>`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your layout to do an horizontal line:

```
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="2dp"
     android:background="#c0c0c0"/>
```

Comment: I guess he wants to `draw a line between two points`. Say, even **diagonally**.

Comment: Dat answer. Dunno if serious or not.